# loginValidation for a web form in C# asp.net application with access db

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, authentication, webforms

I am working with a web form in the asp.net C# , which needs a login for customer and admin and I need to validate the login credentials with the details in my db which is an Access db . 
Any help ???

Comment: If you intend to store user names and passwords in a data base, all i can tell you is... that migth be a wrong idea...

Comment: I dono any other way to keep my users details. i have 700 users only so i think it might be okay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best article(s) and how-tos are [here](http://imar.spaanjaars.com/404/using-the-microsoft-access-providers-to-replace-the-built-in-sql-server-providers). there's a link in the article to create membership for an ASP.NET 4 web site.

Comment: Thank you . The article was really light on my thoughts but that was following the 2005 vs and i am in 2013 and i couldnt use the link for provider specified n the article